# MYSQL Query for listing wordpress users based based on usermeta data

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I am trying to display all users that have a meta data of with a specific value.

So in my case, I have a custom user meta data field called isblogger, with the options yes or no. So I would like to list users that have the isblogger value as yes.

Currently here is the code I have that is dispaying all users

> global $wpdb;
>
> $authors = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT
>   ID, user_nicename FROM $wpdb->users");
>      foreach($authors as $author)  { ?>
>
> list name etc...

Any help on this would be fantastic and much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please click the checkmark beside the best answer to mark it as accepted if it helps you. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add Where condition isblogger='yes'